# Trouble integer parsing two simple strings

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

I'm having trouble integer parsing 2 strings, and concatenating the contained integers. I find when the integer to be parsed exceeds 5 characters in length, when the button is clicked the program/app crashes.

What can I do to fix this? (to make it work with integers exceeding 5 chars in length)

Code:

```
public void SimpleButton (View V){
        int ab = 123456;
        int abc = 223456;

        int a = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(ab) + Integer.toString(abc));

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(a), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
```

Comment: Use a type that can hold larger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MAX_VALUE` of integer is `2,147,483,647` however when you concatenate the `String` values you are getting the number `123,456,223,456` which is much larger than the max value for an integer.  You must use a `Long`.

```
long a = Long.parseLong(Integer.toString(ab) + Integer.toString(abc));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate the `String` forms of the two numbers together, you get a 12-digit number, which is too large to store in an `int`.  The maximum is about 2.1 billion, a 10-digit number.  The constant [`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum possible `int`, `2147483647`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE).

Parse a `long` with [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29), which can handle larger numbers (or reduce the number of digits in `ab` and/or `abc`).  The constant [`Long.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum possible `long`, `9223372036854775807L`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE), which is 19 digits.

```
long a = Long.parseLong(Integer.toString(ab) + Integer.toString(abc));
```